# Scenes for HDR vs SDR comparison

Tags: hdr

I'm currently looking for scenes when I can compare effects of HDR. I have couple of films on BR in 2 versions - one in HDR, second in SDR. My heuristic is to look 2 kinds of scene:

- very bright scene in background, and in very first plan I can see and object - e.g. looking through window during sunny day, with a large object in very first plan
- very dark scene with a couple of small bright points - e.g. street at night with street lights

I think that all, but maybe you have better idea?

In other words, how find good scenes where HDR results are easy to detect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Sunsets and Sunrises
- Battle scenes with fire
- indoor dark scenes with source of light (window during day, lamp during evening)
- concerts
- disco (problems with moving objects...)